# How to put an argument in a RegEx?

Tags: java, regex, string, arguments, argument-passing

So, I am trying to use an argument in a RegEx *pattern* and I can't find a pattern because the argument is a simple String which is contained in the bigger string. Here is the the task itself, which I took from this codingbat.com, so everything to be clear:

> THE Precondition and explanation of the task.
>
> Given a string and a non-empty word string, return a version of the
>   original String where all chars have been replaced by pluses ("+"),
>   except for appearances of the word string which are preserved
>   unchanged.

My code:

```
public String plusOut(String str, String word) {
  if(str.matches(".*(<word>.*<word>){1,}.*") || str.matches(".*(<word>.*<word>.*<word>){1,}.*")) {
  return str.replaceAll(".", "+");  //after finding the argument I can easily exclude it but for now I have a bigger problem in the if-condition
  } else {
  return str;
  }
}
```

Is there a way in Java to match an argument? The above code doesn't work for obvious reasons (`<word>`). How to use the argument `word` in the string RegEx?

**UPDATE**

This is the closest I got but it works only for the last char of the *word* String.

```
public String plusOut(String str, String word) 
{
  if(str.matches(".*("+ word + ".*" + word + "){1,}.*") || str.matches(".*(" + word + ".*" + word + ".*" + word + "){1,}.*") || str.matches(".*("+ word + "){1,}.*")) 
  {     
     return str.replaceAll(".(?<!" + word + ")", "+");
  } else {
     return str;
  }
}
```

Input/Output

plusOut("12xy34", "xy") → "+++y++"  (Expected "++xy++") 
plusOut("12xy34", "1") → "1+++++" (Expected "1+++++") 
plusOut("12xy34xyabcxy", "xy") → "+++y+++y++++y" (Expected "++xy++xy+++xy")

It`s because of the *?* in the RegEx.

Comment: Maybe some input/output will be better for us to understand problem.

Comment: @NeerajJain Example `plusOut("12xy34", "xy") → "++xy++"`  and the word is "xy" but it could come up many times also, and I search for a regex that matches the second argument.

Comment: you mean the `+` is replacing the 1 2 3 4? can you give the link of this from codingbat.com?

Comment: @Baby http://codingbat.com/prob/p170829

Comment: you can't achieve that using regex

Comment: @Baby well, I got it for one char using RegEx lookbehind but it is escaping me the (lookbehind) for more chars. If I can set that to a variable, that would be an universal solution. So, do you know a way to achieve this? Lookbehind for many characters, for Java?

Comment: @user4325010 regex only works for some of it, for other example you are only make it complicated. Im able to achieve this using loop and stringbuilder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it with only patterns, you'll have to write some code apart from the pattern. Try this:

```
public static String plusOut(String input, String word) {

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(word));
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    int start = 0;

    while(matcher.find()) {
        char[] replacement = new char[matcher.start() - start];
        Arrays.fill(replacement, '+');
        builder.append(new String(replacement)).append(word);
        start = matcher.end();
    }
    if(start < input.length()) {
        char[] replacement = new char[input.length() - start];
        Arrays.fill(replacement, '+');
        builder.append(new String(replacement));
    }

    return builder.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatenate it using `+` operator of Java

```
if(str.matches("<"+word+">")){ // Now word will be replaced by the value
//do Anything
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot place arguments inside the regex pattern. You can create a regex object by concatenating variables with the regex pattern parts like this:

```
public String plusOut(String str, String word) 
{
  if(str.matches(".*("+ word + ".*" + word + "){1,}.*") || str.matches(".*(" + word + ".*" + word + ".*" + word + "){1,}.*")) 
  {
     return str.replaceAll(".", "+");
  }
  else
  {
     return str;
  }
}
```